# strange behavior with wcf and powershell

Tags: powershell

Working with Powershell and web service. With powershell I am running and updating a cirensen form . When the powershell compiles, I am calling back the service request Id and updating one property of the form.
Working fine with powershell.
With web servcie I am getting error:

> "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name \'eq\'."

```
Get-SCSMObject -Class $sRClass   -filter  “ID -eq $serviceRequestId” | Set-SCSMObject -Property Source -Value “Other”
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `-Filter` parameter works like that!

Sounds like you probably want to use the `Where-Object` CmdLet:

```
Get-SCSMObject -Class $sRClass |
  Where-Object {$_.ID -eq $serviceRequestId} |
  Set-SCSMObject -Property Source -Value “Other”
```